# Trying to refactor my ruby code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a score attribute starting from *30 points*, and want to *deduct 1 point* for certain criteria it meets. Here is how I write it in a long way:

```
case
when user.growth_rate >= 0.1 && user.growth_rate <= 0.11
user.update(score: 29) if user.score != 29
when user.growth_rate >= 0.11 && user.growth_rate <= 0.12
user.update(score: 28) if user.score != 28
end
```

And the list goes on, Is there a better way/method to do logic like this?

Comment: A solution could be a multiplication with rounding to integers and then subtract, maybe. `(30.0 - (user.growth_rate * 30)).round`

Comment: What if `user.growth_rate` exactly equals `0.11`? Just skip it?

Comment: @mudasobwa There is a missing equal sign I guess,

Comment: What is this `=!` used in the question and in both answers?

Comment: @Stefan Fixed my answer, thanks.

Comment: `... if user.score =! 29` is a nonsense thing to do. There is no `=!` operator, that is two operators: An **assignment** and a **negation**. You are assigning `!29`, which is always `false`, to `user.score`, which is almost certainly not what you want to do.

Comment: We need more details about what you're trying to accomplish. It's not very obvious how the list "goes on" at this point. What happens when `user.growth_rate` hit `0.40`? Is there a simple linear progression of possible `growth_rate` values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be possible to calculate the `score` from the `growth_rate` maybe.

```
score = (30.0 - (user.growth_rate * 10)).floor
user.update(score: score) if user.score != score
```